# copy values to another table after insert to target table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have 2 table. `table1` and `table2`
I want insert values to `table1` and after that same values copy or insert to `table2`.

`id` column in table1 is `AUTO_INCREMENT` but I don't want `AUTO_INCREMENT` in `table2` . just copy `id` and other column from `table1` to `table2` after insert to `table1`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are inserting your values record-by-record you can make it in a single transaction:

```
INSERTS INTO table1 (field1,field2...)
VALUES (value1,value2...);

SELECT @max_id:=max(id)
FROM table1;

INSERT INTO table2 (fields...)
VALUES (@max_id, values...);

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer . but not worked correctly.when 2 table empty and insert value , in table 2 id is NULL . and after insert Second value , id in table1 is 2 and in table2 is 1
this is my code:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare(
   "INSERT INTO users (username, userid, password,type,created) 
   VALUES (:user_name_post, :shenase_post, :password_post, :userManger_post, NOW())
   "

  );
     $statement->bindParam(":user_name_post",$userName);
     $statement->bindParam(":shenase_post",$shenase);
     $statement->bindParam(":password_post",$password);
     $statement->bindParam(":userManger_post",$usermanager);

         $stmt2 = $connection->prepare("SELECT @max_id:=max(id) FROM users");
    $stmt2->execute();


        $stm1=$connection->prepare("INSERT INTO historyuser (id,username, userid,type,data) 
   VALUES (@max_id,:user_name_post, :shenase_post,:userManger_post, NOW())");
        $stm1->bindParam(":user_name_post",$userName);
     $stm1->bindParam(":shenase_post",$shenase);
     $stm1->bindParam(":userManger_post",$usermanager);
```